# c# program exits after OnPowerModeChanged event

Tags: c#, hibernate

I am trying to restart a program after hibernation which works great, but every time after the OnPowerModeChanged event was called the application just exits. Any idea what is going on?

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += OnPowerModeChanged;
        Application.Run();
    }

    private static void OnPowerModeChanged(object sender, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Mode == PowerModes.Resume)
        {
            foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("someprogram"))
            {
                process.Kill(); //works
            }
            Process.Start(@"C:\someprogram.exe"); //works
        }
        //application just exits here???
    }
}
```

Comment: So the existing processes are killed, but a new process isn't started?  Dumb question: but this isn't killing itself, correct?

Comment: the new process is started, but my program exits right after